# Maui app becomes transparent and restarts when it goes into the background (IOS)

Tags: ios, maui

The application works, but the first time it is sent in the background, to switch to another application, it appears transparent and restarts.

Any ideas?

Im using visual studio and debug on iphone local connected. Why the second times it works?

Comment: Can you help explain the issue `it appears transparent and restarts`, better to edit your post and add a screenshot to it, also, what is your iOS, VS and Xcode version?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sound like the app crashes. Have you attached a debugger to see if there are any unhandled exceptions? Without seeing code and debugging output, it will not be possible to help you. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).